# Break out of two nested loops from the middle of the inner loop

Tags: c#

In C#, suppose there are two nested loops (each loop can be either while or for loop). 
In the middle of the inner loop, I would like to break out of both loops when a condition is true,

```
loop1
{
    ...
    loop2
    {
        ...
        (I want to break out of both loops, when some condition is true)
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Is there a more elegant way than

```
loop1
{
    ...
    loop2
    {
        ...
        if (condition)
            break
        ...
    }
    if (condition)
        break
    ...
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'd create a function with these loops and use `return`, because if you had more code after your loop block, calling return would make them not to be executed, that's why I'd put them in a separate function.

Comment: this is one of the few times it's generally accepted as allowable to use a `goto` statement.  Though there are other ways to solve the problem

Comment: @Jonesopolis I don't know if this is an exact duplicate. A `goto` would be fine but it could also be wrapped in a function and returned. Which is what I would do. And isn't an exact duplicate of the other question.

Answer (score 1):

Put it in a method and `return`;

```
public void TheLoops() 
{
    while(true) {
        while(true) {
            if (condition) {
                return;
                // or change void to a type and
                // return conditionResult;
            }
        }
    }
}
```